# cannot get decimal value when multiplying string in decimal format and integer

Tags: vb.net

I have a table which has price in decimal data type, quantity in integer and Amount in decimal.

When I multiply price (decimal) with quantity(integer), I get amount rounded off and value after decimal point becomes zero.

Note: I get price as parameter value,which is string.

Example: 20.5(price) * 1(quantity) = 20.00(amount).

I tried the following but does not work.

```
amount = decimal.parse(price) * quantity.text
```

Please help.

Comment: You will need to show your code, otherwise we cannot help you. Please *edit your question* to create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem.

Comment: What type is `amount` BTW?

Comment: amount is decimal data type

Comment: Then i can't see what's your problem. See [how this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PvAR9a) is working as expected. Debug your `price` variable

Comment: @pikok sorry. I got it. I forgot to change the datatype of amount to decimal in my SQL class. That was the problem. Now it is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to convert the string value of price to a double before multiplying it, for example like this:

```
Dim price as String = "20.5"
Dim quantity as integer = 1
Dim total = Convert.ToDecimal(price) * quantity
Console.WriteLine(total)
```

Which gives 20.5

Comment: I'd advise to **never** use `Double` for money operations.That's what `Decimal` is for

Comment: @Icepickle it still does not work. please note that I get price as parameter value.thanks

Comment: @Pikoh Fair enough :) changed it ToDecimal

Comment: @Sonam Does not work is not a statement that is helpful, what is not working? And are you sure amount is not accidentally an integer?

Comment: sorry guys. I got it. I forgot to change the datatype of amount to decimal in my SQL class. That was the problem. Now it is solved. Thanks.

Comment: @Icepickle my amount data type was accidentally integer in my SQL class. You were right. Thanks a lot guys.